# How to extract only first line that matches each pattern from a file?

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a text file that looks like

```
Line_A 123
Line_A 456
Line_A 789
Line_B 123
Line_B 456
Line_B 789
Line_C 123
Line_C 456
Line_C 789
```

And a reference file that looks like this:

```
 Line_A
 Line_B
 Line_C
```

I want to extract the first line from the text file that matches each name in the reference file like this:

```
Line_A 123
Line_B 123
Line_C 123
```

So far I can only get the first line from the first match with:

```
grep -A1 -w -f  reference.txt -m 1 file.txt
```

Maybe I need a for loop? TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in Awk with a single pass over the files as long as you list the reference file first in the argument list:

```
awk 'FNR == NR { name[$1] = 0; }
     FNR != NR { for (i in name) if ($0 ~ i && name[i]++ == 0) { print $0; break; } }' \
    reference.txt file.txt
```

With the sample inputs, this yields the required output.

This is a fairly standard technique in Awk.  You read the first file using the `FNR == NR` condition (file line number equal to overall line number; only true for lines in the first file) and save appropriate information for later use.  Often, people use a `next` in the first line; it works.  It means they can avoid
the `FNR != NR` condition — I like that for symmetry.

When processing the second and subsequent files, check whether each of the names read from the first file matches a line, and the name hasn't been printed before, printing the line if it hasn't been handled.  The break avoids checking other names if the current name matches.

This is the way many people would write the command; it also works.

```
awk 'FNR == NR { name[$1] = 0; next }
     { for (i in name) if ($0 ~ i && name[i]++ == 0) { print $0; break; } }' \
    reference.txt file.txt
```

Both versions of the code here look for the name anywhere in the line; if you strictly want to match the `$1` of the second (or subsequent) files, you can alter the conditions (indeed, simplify them).  And [karakfa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1435869/karakfa) [shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50263733/15168) deleting matches when they're matched (instead of incrementing a counter), which is better for performance as you don't have to continue matching that which is no longer relevant.  However, the code shown here would be simpler to adapt to showing the second, or third, or last entry for a given name (handling second or third involves changing the 0 to 1 or 2; handling 'last' requires more substantial changes).

Answer (score 3):

another `awk`

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} $1 in a{delete a[$1]; print}' reference file
```

keep the references in a set, when seen in the file print the line and remove reference, so only the first instance will be printed.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another awk:

```
$ awk 'a[$1]++==1' ref file
Line_A 123
Line_B 123
Line_C 123
```

Read both files in above order, count each string in first column and print when it's seen the second time. This will fail if there are strings in `file` that are not in `reference`. In that case use one of the other solutions.

Comment: smart +1.  will also fail if there are duplicates in the reference.